# HP laptop booting for install ubuntu?

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox

I am trying to boot my hp laptop but it still showing me some problem? How can i boot my hp elitebook laptop for ubuntu or linux environment?

Comment: @Falguni Islam Windows Live USB making instructions https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0  Ubuntu LiveUSB making instructions https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0  How to install instructions https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

Answer (score 0):

Download the ubuntu iso file from the ubuntu website.  Create a usb boot stick and boot with this stick. Install ubuntu. After installation reboot.